# Play separate video and audio simultaneously in android's videoview

Tags: android, audio, android-videoview

I'm trying to play simultaneously a video and a different audio track from the video. I use a video view :

```
VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
video.setVideoPath(filename);
video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
video.start();
video.requestFocus();
```

Is it possible to handle this extra audio with MediaPlayer or I have to use SoundPool or AudioTrack ? If so, how can I be sur the audio and the video will be play in sync.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the video as normal, and then play the sound from a service running in the background. The service could contain a MediaPlayer for playing separate sound

About services: [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

And from your VideoView you can start the service by:

```
    playbackServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicPlayerService.class);
    getActivity().startService(playbackServiceIntent);
```

There might be issues with regards sound sync, but might be worth a try.